# Laravel: How to make one collection out of array of collections?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I use this query to get ids into a variable:

```
$ids = DB::table('note_user')->select('note_id')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get('note_id');
```

Since I have two notes that belong to one user I get

```
[{"note_id":1},{"note_id":2}]
```

This appears to be an array of collections and every [Laravel collection method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods) I attempt to apply to it returns an error. For example,

```
$flattened = $ids->flatMap(function ($values) {
    return $values;
});
```

returns

> Fatal error: Call to a member function flatMap() on array

Is there any way to turn

```
[{"note_id":1},{"note_id":2}]
```

into

`[1, 2]`?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to this is to use `pluck` instead.

```
$ids = DB::table('note_user')->select('note_id')->where('user_id', $user_id)->pluck('note_id');
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_pluck

This returns only an array of integers like you want.